# Why Monte Carlo sampling is not needed for reparameterization trick?

Tags: gradient-descent, reinforcement-learning, gumbel-distribution

To esitimate $\nabla_\theta \mathbb{E}_{z\sim p_\theta(z)}[f(z)]$, we have two options:

1. REINFORCE: $\nabla_\theta \mathbb{E}_{z\sim p_\theta(z)}[f(z)] =  \mathbb{E}_{z\sim p_\theta(z)}[ f(z)\nabla_\theta log(p_\theta(z))]$, we need Monte Carlo sampling to solve the last expectation, i.e., we need this: $\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^{N} f(z_i)\nabla_\theta log(p_\theta(z_i))$
2. Reparameterization: $ \nabla_\theta \mathbb{E}_{z\sim p_\theta(z)}[f(z)]
                                       = \nabla_\theta \mathbb{E}_{\epsilon\sim p_\theta(\epsilon)}[f(g(\theta, \epsilon))]
                                       = \mathbb{E}_{\epsilon\sim p_\theta(\epsilon)}[\nabla_\theta f(g(\theta, \epsilon))]
   $. A typical example of this is Gumbel-Softmax.

My question is, why do we need Monte-Carlo to sample multiple $x$'s in REINFORCE, while in reparameterization trick, we typically only sample one $\epsilon$ from $p_\theta(\epsilon)$.

Comment: I don't think this is correct. A3C & SVG-0 both use minibatches in a similar way. You likely need less for reparameterization due to lower variance.

Comment: @DaVinci do you mean both REINFORCE and reparameterization use Monte-Carlo?